# How can I debug when a cron job isn't executed in a certain docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, cron

What I have done is:

```
docker run --rm -it SomeCentOsBasedImage   
(in a docker container)   
yum update -y   
yum install -y vim cronie python3   
vim /script.sh   
   #!/bin/bash   
   echo "a" >> /target.txt   
chmod 777 script.sh   
crontab -e   
   * * * * * /script.sh   
crond -n   
# indented lines should be written in the above file.
```

But this doesn't work.

The `target.txt` file isn't generated.

I checked `crontab -l`, and it showed `* * * * * /script.sh`.

When I do the exact same operations in `docker run --rm -it centos:7` container, `target.txt` file is generated properly.

I have to debug this problem, but all I can do is just checking `crontab -l`.

What else can I do for this?

Thanks :)

+ My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM centos:7

RUN localedef -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 && \
        yum update -y
RUN yum install -y python3 cronie vim && \
        pip3 install requests

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

CMD ["crond", "-n"]
```

`crontab` file:

```
➜  issue4 git:(feature/issue-4) cat crontab
* * * * * python3 /app/hello.py >> /var/log/cron.log
```

In this way, a log file is generated at /var/log.

But when I change the base image to an extended one(`FROM Some.Registry.com/centos7`), the log isn't generated.

Comment: Is cron running in the container? But running cron in a container is a weird idea. Normally you start a regular container from cron.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, cron doesn't run inside a container at all. You shouldn't think of containers as being like virtual machines, even though they look similar on the inside.

Usually, only a single process runs in the container. So, you'd have to deliberately install and start crond (the cron daemon) and then add that to the command you use when starting the container, if you really want crons *inside* the container.

Normally you would run the crons outside the container, although the cron commands themselves might interact with your container.

Now, to answer your original question - unfortunately there's not enough information to say why it works with centos:7 and fails with an image that extends centos:7. It's possible you installed cron inside a different container from the same image and your modifications were lost when you ran the app a second time. I just can't tell from here.

When you say `(in a docker container)` that's not enough information. Did you `docker exec` into an already running container?

Regardless, although what you want is totally possible, it's unusual to do it this way.

Comment: Yes, when I `docker exec` into the container, and do `ps -ef` command, the results are the same. I thought that I should run a cron job inside the container because a platform requires a docker image, makes it as an app, and runs the app in a cluster. And what I want for my app is to run a certain python file every minute. I don't have any control with the app running environment, so it seemed difficult to run a cron job in the outer environment. Can I resolve this problem in another way?

Comment: Hi @yoon, it's still not clear to me how you installed cron inside the container. Did you add it to the Dockerfile? Or did you install it by doing `docker exec`? Or some other way? Depending on what your cron job needs to do, and what it needs access to, you can run the cron job in a separate container from an image that runs only cron. There are lots of these on Docker Hub

Comment: Hi, I added my Dockerfile. Please refer to this code. In the real code, cron job will not just print hello, but run a python file that reads a mail box, and sends some of the mails with a certain rule.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on this. So it seems you have a container just for cron - I thought perhaps you were trying to add cron to an existing container that runs other processes. The fact it's just for cron makes this easier. Can I suggest you just use a ready-made cron container such as https://hub.docker.com/r/willfarrell/crontab , instead of centos:7?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I can only use this container for some reasons. Only this container is guaranteed for a certain cluster. I just wanted to know what can cause this not to work, even though a `crontab -l`, `ps -ef` show the smae.